# fetching data from outside API in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an external API with its `Content-Type`, `Authorization` key, and `tenant` fields. The description of API is like this:

```
URL: https://url_address.com/
method: POST

Header:
    Content-Type:       application/json
    Authorization:      Basic asfvasvGasfssfafssDGDggGDgDSggsdfgsd=

Body: -> raw : 
    {
           "Tenant" : "devED"
    }
```

I try to fetch these data from my `django` views with this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic asfvasvGasfssfafssDGDggGDgDSggsdfgsd='}
Body = { "Tenant": 'devED' }
GetAPI_response = requests.post('https://url_address.com/', headers=headers, params=Body).json()
```

But it says errors like:

```
{'Message': 'Request data is in Bad Format.'}
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 2.4.2, `requests.post` can be passed a `json` parameter that will be automatically encoded and will set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` meaning you don't have to set it yourself

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
body = {'Tenant': 'devED'}
response = requests.post('https://url_address.com/', headers=headers, json=body)
```

Comment: Adding to the answer, `params` is for URL parameters. For POST request body, there is `data` and `json` keywords.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just searching for this.